# Array objetos em angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Estou fazendo desta forma para preencher o `array`:

```
let form1 = this.formGroup.get('array_activity') as FormArray;
    console.log(form1);
    if (!this.data.isEdit) {
    for (let i = 0; i < form1.controls.length; i++) {  
      this.activity.name = form1.at(i).get('name').value;
      this.activity.qtd = form1.at(i).get('qtd').value;
      this.activity.unit = form1.at(i).get('unit').value;
      
      this.phase.activities.push(this.activity);
      console.log(this.activity);
   }

   console.log(this.phase.activities);
```

Porém desta forma, por exemplo, se eu adiciono 1 e 2, ele adiciona 2 e 2, se adiciona 1,2 e 3, ele fica 3,3 e 3.
Ele pega a quantidade e parece que está adicionando só o ultimo.
Quando dou um `console.log(this.activity);` dentro do `for`, os valores estão corretos.
Alguma ideia, e explicação do que pode ser ? Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver fazendo desta forma:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < form1.controls.length; i++) {  
  this.phase.activities.push({
  name:form1.at(i).get('name').value,
  qtd: form1.at(i).get('qtd').value,
  unit: form1.at(i).get('unit').value,
});
}
```